# How to delete one specific row using Row_Number() in SQLITE?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, row-number

I am new to SQL and I want to be able to perform a query to delete a certain row (NOT duplicated rows) in a table which does not have a PK (for research/learning purpose).

```
|--------------------------Users---------------------------|
|-ID (PK, AutoIncrement, NN)-|-username(NN)-|-password(NN)-|
|-            1             -|-    abc     -|-     abc    -|
|-            2             -|-    123     -|-     123    -|
|-            3             -|-    qwe     -|-     qwe    -|
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

```
|---------------------------SavedCarts----------------------------|
|- user(FK references Users("id")) -|- cart_content VARCHAR(255) -|
|-               1                 -|- egg,3,milk,4,bread,4      -|
|-               1                 -|- egg,3,milk,1              -|
|-               1                 -|- egg,3,milk,2,cookie,6     -|
|-               2                 -|- egg,3,milk,3              -|
|-               2                 -|- egg,6,milk,5,cereal,5     -|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

In this example, the "SavedCarts" table saves the cart's content of the logged in user. I want to delete for example "row number 3" from the SavedCarts table.

I was able to perform SELECT queries that returns ALL the cart_content of **user 1** with the following script:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY user) RowNum, 
cart_content 
FROM SavedCarts 
WHERE user = 1;
```

And I was able to perform a SELECT query which returns ONLY a certain cart_content of **user 1** with the following script:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user) RowNum FROM SavedCarts ) 
WHERE user = 1 AND RowNum = 3;
```

However, I could not make it work while implementing the same logic in deleting a specific row in the table (Maybe I did something wrong in the delete script). I know it is way easier to just include a PK in the table but this is for learning purpose. I have been searching online and I can only find others using ROW_NUMBER() to delete duplicate rows(which I tried using their logic as well). Can anyone tell me if deleting a row with ROW_NUMBER() is possible and suggest to me on how to achieve it?

Thank you!

I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM SavedCarts 
WHERE (user) IN (
   SELECT user FROM (
      SELECT user, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user) AS rownum 
      FROM SavedCarts
   ) 
   WHERE user = ? AND rownum = ?
);
```

```
DELETE FROM SavedCarts 
WHERE user IN (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user) AS rownum 
      FROM SavedCarts
   ) 
   WHERE rownum = ?
);
(this deletes everything of user 1);
```

```
DELETE FROM SavedCarts 
WHERE user = ? AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user) = ?;
```

Edit:
I have tried CTE, but I am getting this error:
[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: CTE).
**Is this because SQLITE does not support CTE?**
Is there a way to achieve this without CTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to delete for example "row number 3" from the SavedCarts table.

You can do it as :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT rowid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY rowid) AS RowNum
  FROM SavedCarts
  WHERE user = 1
)
DELETE FROM SavedCarts
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM cte WHERE RowNum = 3);
```

Comment: This worked for me! I was able to delete the one specific row with this without the error "No such table: CTE" I was getting (Sorry I do not have enough reputation to upvote an answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS RowNum
  FROM SavedCarts
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE user = 1 AND RowNum = 3;
```

- CTE creates a temporary result set with an additional RowNum column, which is the row number for each user
- Then delete the row you want by specifying the user and RowNum values in the WHERE clause of the DELETE statement

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I am using SQLITE driver in a Javafx application. I remember reading that SQLITE does not support CTE from a post from 2013, and I do not know if it is still the case. I am getting an error : "[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: CTE)". Is there a way to achieve this without CTE?